# Autoreject calls via predefined SMS message while away from phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms, auto-reject

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo there is a neat feature where when you receive a call you can type on a predefined text message to send. I wonder whether the following scenario can be achieved on Android phones:

- The user is away from the phone, perhaps having a shower or working out at the gym.
- The user (sets up and then) selects a predefined text message (saved in a list of predefined text messages).
- The user specifies that whenever a phone call is received, the corresponding text message will be sent to the caller's phone number automatically (and this could be set up either for everyone or just for a few phone numbers the user wants to share this info with).

If a caller rings twice from the same number, there would also be an option to send the SMS only the first time (so as to not have some malicious user deplete all your SMS credit).

Answer (score 1):

With [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) or [Qpython](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpy3) (Python Script Engine) you can use android apps permission .(E.g With it you can send mesaages, take picture etc.)

If you have basic knowlege of python you can make a script that will help you to do that.

You will also need tasker etc. To launch script

[I think it will be hard task to do it.I just gave you the Base Idea.Hope you will make it]

Comment: Thank you for your response. +I know python, tcl, and shell scripting, but I'm not sure about how to proceed.

Comment: You can first install the Qpython3 then after importing SL4A module you can go through its documentation. and see how can you use messageing feature in creative way to solve your problem.